# Choice of solder influencing quartz crystal?

Tags: soldering, crystal

I had problems with `DS1307` based real time clocks, the culprit seems to be the solder we used. Let me explain.

We were using an [Adafruit DS1307 based RTC I2C module](http://www.adafruit.com/products/264) on a stock Raspberry Pi. The clocks were built - and found to be communicating ok (eg. I2C was good), but not "ticking", eg. the second was not advancing. Building them on a breadboard (not soldering) led to working clocks, so the module itself was out of the question.
Also the electrical connection between crystal and IC, as tested by a simple multimeter, passed on *all* units.

Further investigation and narrowing things down with my trusted [bus pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate) (a god sent device for us without heavy testing equipment!) lead me to re-solder the connections with my own (ie. what I use at home) solder - and voilà, they worked. Further narrowing down showed that I actually only had to clean and re-solder the connections of the crystal quartz, not even the IC side had to be re soldered.

**Does anyone know or have an idea or explanation why**
`S-Pb60Sn40` does *not*,
`S-Sn60Pb36Cu1` *does* work in connecting the crystal quartz to the PCB well, eg. in a way that the `DS1307` starts ticking?
The large difference between the solder used seems to be in approximately swapped proportions of lead and tin used, but maybe the 1% copper does it's job somehow?
My further guess would be this has something to do with the choice of solder somehow damping the oscillator, but the "how" of it still leaves me baffled.

For the statistics: We have soldered 87 units with the "bad" solder, none of them working (eg. "ticking"). I have manually re-soldered 53 of them now, all working. For 48 of those I only de-, the re-soldered the crystal oscillator connections.

**Edit 1** - Cleaning the solder pads
As proposed by some of you, I manually cleaned a number of PCBs with 70% isopropyl alcohol and/or pure water - no avail, the clocks still did not "tick" away. Only de-, then re-soldering the two crystal connectors makes them start ticking.

**Edit 2** - The type of solder I used
The solder that did *not* work is [this product from Stannol](http://www.stannol.de/en/products/solder-wires/?tx_produktselektor_filter%5Baa_prod%5D=S321&tx_produktselektor_filter%5Baction%5D=show&tx_produktselektor_filter%5Bcontroller%5D=Product), the one that *does* work is [this product from Felder Löttechnik GmbH](http://www.felder.de/tl_files/felder/pdf/Produktinformationen/18/18-ISO-Core%20RA,%20Bleihaltig.pdf) (pdf in german, sorry, they don't seem to have an english version online).

**Edit 3** - The flux that is in the solder (aka. getting closer...)
The non-working Stannol solder uses flux of type 2.1.2.A - that is, [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_%28metallurgy%29) an organic, water-soluble liquid (?? this seems to be wrong!) flux with halides. The *working* solder from Felder uses flux of type 1.1.2.B, that is resin, rosin based solid flux with halides.
\$\Longrightarrow\$ The culprit could either be the unknown "organic, water soluble" flux from Stannol or the different solder formula with added copper from Felder.

Comment: Did your solder by any chance have water-soluble flux that was not cleaned from the board?

Comment: @tut - That would be my vote, based on similar experience of unclean crystals failing to start.

Comment: @JohnU Yes, we ran into this a long time ago at a place I worked where the manager rushed out an order of motherboards without cleaning the water-soluble flux. The RTC oscillators began failing on the first rainy day.

Comment: You might try manually resoldering a few using the "bad" solder.   You may find that it's about the connection being made, rather than the material.  Mostly for curiosity, since the answers regarding flux and so forth still apply, and you'll want to use the proper solder in the automated process.

Comment: It's risky to jump to conclusions if you want a correct answer, rather than a one off fix. While flux seems a likely culprit it's not certain. Sometimes you can get oxidation on pins that is quite resistant to soldering ("solderability" can be a black art) and it may be that the  1% Cu worked some alcamistical magic in working on a corrosion layer. If you have more units unsoldered (as it sounds like you have) you could try mechanically cleaning the pins first with sandpaper and/or scalpel or similar and then solder with "bad" solder to see what happens. Also check PCB solderability.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps it's an issue with barely enough capacitance on the crystal to start the oscillator properly.  That would explain why it worked great on the breadboard.  Different amounts of solder will vary this slightly.

Comment: Upvoting for the careful analysis including statistics of the "fix". I learnt something today. Thanks

Comment: @RussellMcMahon We tried scraping/sanding/alcohol-ing/aceton-ing (not necessarily in that order ;) the crystal pins to no avail. The leads not "taking" the solder was one of my first-ish guesses, also.

Comment: Desperation :-) - also check PCB solderability. Old PCBs can tarnish nastily. With new ones, if the manufacturer has aimed them at a lead free process this may cause issues, but this would be expected to show up elsewhere as well.

Comment: Hey, what happened to that other answer? It seemed to explain what was going on vs. "its the flux". Was it entirely wrong? It was kinda weird, felt like Tony Stewart, but the answer could have been cleaned up?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The PCB is of (for my eyes) excellent quality. Shiny coppery through-holes that take the solder quite easily. I can't find anything abou ROHS/lead free solder at adafruit's site, though I have asked them via email about this issue.

Comment: @Tut Do you know of a good source of "flux information", ie. sites that teach me a bit more about which fluxes are water soluble and which ones are not? The maker of my solder, Stannol, has it's staff currently sent away to an exhibition.

Comment: @Christian It's looking more and more like flux cleaning may not be the answer in your case as these failures would occur after the flux has had time to absorb moisture from the (humid) air, however: The main source for information regarding solder fluxes comes from the manufacturers. The [Stannol link](http://www.stannol.de/en/products/solder-wires/?tx_produktselektor_filter%5Baa_prod%5D=S321&tx_produktselektor_filter%5Baction%5D=show&tx_produktselektor_filter%5Bcontroller%5D=Product) you provided indicates "Residues must be removed" and "Residues are easily soluble in water".

Comment: @Christian RTC oscillators should not be this finicky. It may be time to re-evaluate the oscillator design including: exact components used (including part#s), board layout (and material?), solder and anything else that may be pertinent. This would probably better be served in another question. Also how accurate are the working oscillators? Fast or slow and by how much? This could provide a clue regarding component selection such as capacitors.

Comment: @Tut Very interesting questions - thanks for the idea. I will set a number of clocks and let them run over the long weekend (here in germany ;). I'll report back on monday on this.

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is almost certainly not a direct issue with the solder itself but with the flux in the solder. Many fluxes leave a conductive film on the board which must be removed for circuits such as yours.

Note that RTC chips try to be extremely low power so as to preserve the battery as much as possible. As such, the biasing of the 32.768KHz crystal for the oscillator is designed to be rather low current (i.e. high impedance circuit). The flux conductivity can sometimes be low enough to completely swamp out and literally short out the oscillator preventing it from working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you mind listing a couple flux types that are conductive?  I was only aware of muriatic acid fluxes being conductive, but they aren't typically used for electronics.

Comment: I tried cleaning 12 random PCBs with 70% isopropyl alcohol and 14 random PCBs with simple water; none of the > 40 PCBs I visually inspected had visible deposits of flux between the solder pads of the crystal. Cleaning the PCB did not change anything, ie. the clocks were still not ticking. Though your assumption makes a lot of sense, it seems to be something *in* the composition of the solder itself.

Comment: @TimH The "conductive" fluxes I am familiar with are those that are water-soluble which become partially conductive as they absorb moisture from the air. An example of a water-soluble flux is [Kester 331 Organic Flux](http://www.kester.com/products/product/331-Flux-Cored-Wire/).

Comment: I see what you mean.  Organic acid fluxes also will really damage the board (bad corrosion) if they are left on the PCB, so proper a assembly process should always include cleaning off the OA flux.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use hot glue to fix the crystal case to the PCB in order to inhibit parasitic vibration.  Soldering the case to the PCB is more thorough if somebody was smart enough to give you a pad for that, but it doesn't look like it.

If the can is just touching the board such that it can possibly buzz, that's about the worst case for parasitic loss of energy.

Comment: Thanks, but as strange as it sounds, the issue was indeed wrong solder. Not the flux, but the solder...